# How to turn off automatic encryption for core data in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a large core data store that I dont care about encryption.  I am worried about the overhead of the automatic encryption so I am trying to disable it.

[The quote from the docs is](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1):

> For applications built for iOS 5.0 or later, persistent stores now store data by default in an encrypted format on disk.

This is the code I am using, its not crashing, but im not 100% sure is doing anything.  (I got the constant names from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSFileProtectionNone)).

```
NSDictionary* optionsDictionary = [NSDictionary 
                                   dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionNone 
                                   forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];

if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                   configuration:nil
                                   URL:storeURL
                                   options:optionsDictionary
                                   error:&error]) {
```

- Is this the right code?
- How can I tell if has stopped encryption?

Comment: If you have not measured that the file operation is slow this would be a premature optimization.

Comment: I heartily concur with @CocoaFu. Don't "worry" about something, test it. Generate a big store of test data and see if encryption imposes any significant penalty.

Comment: Agree with the above two comments. But if are really curious to know if it's actually keeping the file unencrypted, why not just turn on iTunes File Sharing and taking a look at the sqlite database using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, that code should turn off all the file protection even on iOS5. You can't easily test it, however.

Answer (score 3):

Robert,

All encryption on iOS is performed in hardware. I, and the Apple engineers I've spoken with, would be really surprised if you saw any performance difference with an encrypted filesystem. (Flash on iOS devices is so slow that you will not see the encryption delays.)

As your above commenters suggest, use the simulator and the runtime system that shows you the SQL that is actually issued for your fetches to see what the performance differences between you two fetches actually are.

Andrew

Comment: Ok fair enough, from what your saying it sounds like its fast. I have a 40mb store full of lat lon points.  Pushing the points onto the map fast is mission critical.  I thought turning off encryption would be a no-brainer since its 1 line of code.  I can't believe im being slated so much for it! Iv got no way of profiling it anyway so I cant really tell if its doing anything.

Comment: Robert, your performance is dominated by the fetches to the flash. Hence, your schema and index structure is probably the most important thing you need to design. Obviously, that schema is going to be affected by your queries. They need to co-evolve. Andrew